# How to use Google AutoML on web app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, automl, google-cloud-automl

I have a Google Cloud AutoML NL model ready to use. I wish to link this with my web app with Firebase backend. Following is my code to call. There is authorization issue. I want to understand how to authorize the app to help the client apps get access to AutoML model.

```
async add(data){
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type:application/json')

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}

var request = new Request('https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project1/locations/us-central1/models/TCN5678:predict', options )

var response = await fetch(request)

var status = await response.status
console.log(status)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for hours, finally I could resolve this. I am not sure how it can work for, other than Firebase (and NL AutoML). I used Firebase Cloud Function to work around and used a [hidden doc](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/automl/0.1.x/v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient) which gives access to AutoML npm. The given code require some changes. Firebase CF is able to authenticate without explicitly authorizing. Following is a suggested code and I am able to get the classification of prediction with AutoML. Hope it helps others too. Lastly, it seems Google docs is a way of testing searching skills and patience, not sure how it helps them:

```
const automl = require('@google-cloud/automl');
exports.sendToAML = functions.database.ref('/path/to/text').onWrite((snapshot, context) =>{


var client = new automl.PredictionServiceClient({
  // optional auth parameters.
});

var formattedName = client.modelPath('bucketId', 'us-central1', 'TCN****3567595');
var payload = {
  "textSnippet": {
       "content": snapshot.after._data.text,
        "mime_type": "text/plain"
   },
};
var request = {
  name: formattedName,
  payload: payload,
};
client.predict(request)
  .then(responses => {
    var response = responses[0];
    return console.log(response.payload[0].classification.score)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

`

Comment: Hey Disu - Cheers, please can you share how this can be done on Streamlit, i.e, to call the AutoML model from streamlit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should either use [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#service_accounts) or [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#top_of_page) as the authentication method. Try to avoid the use of API keys as your credentials could be exposed and misused, generating undesired charges.

Comment: Thanks. I had gone through all these. If you can be more specific, it can help...